# How to parse child document Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i get child document mongodb

android retriving data and read them

NodeJS+MongoDB

```
 [ { pinNumber: '4',
   nameDevice: 'den ngu',
   pintype: 0,
   deleted: '0',
   status: '0',
   laston: '31 thg 5, 2017 10:53:02' },
 { pinNumber: '9',
   nameDevice: 'quat ngu',
   pintype: 0,
   deleted: '0',
   status: '0',
   laston: '31 thg 5, 2017 10:54:14' },
 { pinNumber: '4',
   nameDevice: 'den',
   pintype: 0,
   deleted: '0',
   status: '0',
   space_id: '592cf576a53411474242b5fa',
   laston: '31 thg 5, 2017 11:45:31' } ] }
```

i can't parse them, help me!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to parse this json in java you can look at this :
[How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

> import org.json.*;
>
> JSONObject data = new JSONObject("you json here");
>
> for(int i=0 ;i < data.length() ; i++){
>
> String pinNumber = data.getJSONObject(i).getString("pinNumber");
>
> }

Downloadable jar: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

You seem to have a extra '}' in the end in your json.